# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Could not find template'

Tags: joomla

I haven't done any work on my Joomla site in a while- no new changes. I just visited the home page and it returns this error. Any ideas on what this may be?

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Could not find template "yoo_avenue".' in /hermes/bosweb25b/b905/ipg.stokestackbbqcom/avenue/libraries/cms/application/site.php:510 Stack trace: #0 /hermes/bosweb25b/b905/ipg.stokestackbbqcom/avenue/libraries/legacy/error/error.php(778): JApplicationSite->getTemplate() #1 /hermes/bosweb25b/b905/ipg.stokestackbbqcom/avenue/plugins/system/redirect/redirect.php(130): JError::customErrorPage(Object(InvalidArgumentException)) #2 [internal function]: PlgSystemRedirect::handleError(Object(InvalidArgumentException)) #3 {main} thrown in /hermes/bosweb25b/b905/ipg.stokestackbbqcom/avenue/libraries/cms/application/site.php on line 510

Comment: Did you do any updates? (As in "oh, there are updates available.  Let me just click this button..." ;-) happened to me a lot of times... )

Comment: This question is about Joomla management and not programming as defined for StackOverflow, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)